# How to calculate top n percent of sum with group by and put others in "Other" category similar to crystal reporting does with group sorting/ filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server

Similar to crystal reports where you can implement the custom group sorting to sort and filter by top n percent  for the groups of a sum field and place the remaining records in an Other category, how can I do this same in SQL
[Example of crystal reports feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8otg9.png)

| CustomerName | Cost | Fees | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc customer | 200.10 | 20449.00 | 1 | 2021 |
| abc customer | 240.10 | 24440.10 | 1 | 2021 |
| abc customer | 345.55 | 3455559.10 | 2 | 2021 |
| abc customer | 34444.44 | 45555.55 | 2 | 2021 |
| def customer | 3401.22 | 3333.11 | 1 | 2021 |
| def customer | 23444.43 | 444442.12 | 1 | 2021 |
| ghi customer | 3202.11 | 9873.01 | 3 | 2021 |
| ghi customer | 5421.01 | 89033.33 | 1 | 2021 |
| jkl customer | 22.02 | 0.02 | 2 | 2021 |
| jkl customer | 333.03 | 0.33 | 3 | 2021 |
| mno customer | 2.05 | 0.01 | 3 | 2021 |
| mno customer | 333.05 | 0.03 | 2 | 2021 |
| pqr customer | 44.06 | 0.01 | 2 | 2021 |
| pqr customer | 44.06 | 0.01 | 1 | 2021 |

In Microsoft SQL, I need to write a query similar to Crystal Reports that groups by customer, month, and year, and filters the top 90 percent of the sum of the Fees columns and then gathers anything that didnt get in the top 90% in Others summarizing the Cost and Fees in one row.

So assuming jkl, mno, and pqr customers didnt make the top 90%,
those records would come back like this

| CustomerName | Cost | Fees | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Others | 44.06 | 0.01 | 1 | 2021 |
| Others | 399.13 | 0.06 | 2 | 2021 |
| Others | 335.08 | 0.34 | 3 | 2021 |

And the rest of the records that made the top 90% would be their normal customer name, sum of cost, sum of fees, month, year grouped by customername, month, and year

Comment: tag your database and provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to whether by "top 90%" you mean 90th percentile or are less than 90% of the max value. The query for either is basically the same, but 90% of max value is what I think you're going for so it should be as follows:

```
select sub_query.*
from 
    (
    select CustomerName, sum(Cost) [Cost], sum(Fees) [Fees], Month, Year
    from table
    group by CustomerName, Month, Year 
    ) sub_query
    left join (
        select max(fees) * 0.9 [fees]
        from (
            select CustomerName, sum(Cost) [Cost], sum(Fees) [Fees], Month, Year
            from table
            group by CustomerName, Month, Year 
        ) sub_query2 
    ) filter_query on 1 = 1 /*The subquery only returns 1 row so we need to force a one-to-many join*/
where 
    sub_query.fees < filter_query.fees
```

**After comment:** The comment cleared some things up. You want to display the details (aggregates by CustomerName, Month, Year) for all records that are 90% of max fees of that aggregate and append a summary (aggregates by just month, year) of all records that don't meet that filter. This should do what you want.

```
select sub_query.*
from 
    (
    select CustomerName, sum(Cost) [Cost], sum(Fees) [Fees], Month, Year
    from table
    group by CustomerName, Month, Year 
    ) sub_query
    left join (
        select max(fees) * 0.9 [fees]
        from (
            select CustomerName, sum(Cost) [Cost], sum(Fees) [Fees], Month, Year
            from table
            group by CustomerName, Month, Year 
        ) sub_query2 
    ) filter_query on 1 = 1 /*The subquery only returns 1 row so we need to force a one-to-many join*/
where 
    sub_query.fees >= filter_query.fees
union all
select 'Others', sum(Cost) [Cost], sum(Fees) [Fees], Month, Year
from 
    (
   select CustomerName, sum(Cost) [Cost], sum(Fees) [Fees], Month, Year
    from table
    group by CustomerName, Month, Year 
    ) sub_query
    left join (
        select max(fees) * 0.9 [fees]
        from (
            select CustomerName, sum(Cost) [Cost], sum(Fees) [Fees], Month, Year
            from table
            group by CustomerName, Month, Year 
        ) sub_query2 
    ) filter_query on 1 = 1 /*The subquery only returns 1 row so we need to force a one-to-many join*/
where 
    sub_query.fees < filter_query.fees
group by [Fees], Month, Year
```

Comment: Thanks so much. In Crystal Reports, under group sort, you are able to sort and filter the groups out by top n % of a summary field (in this case fees) and place the remaining records summarized and grouped in to "Others" records based on the group condition. This is what I am looking for and towards the end of the post, you will see an example of how the Others records would look like in the results

Comment: I've updated the answer. It's hard to give code-snippets because I can't test it but it should give you what you want. Note, this query is not optimized and may be slow on larger datasets.